# Black triangles in my render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, shadows

I am trying to render a terrain using Digital Elevation Model. During my render I am getting blacks spots/triangles in my render. I tried recalculating normals, applying subdivision modifier, shade smooth etc. But still I am getting black spots

The portion of my render screenshot attached,

[image]

Comment: maybe go in the Object Data > Geometry > and Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Comment: Have you decimated your geometry?

Comment: I am very basic blender user

Comment: In the current work custom split normals data is not added

Comment: I tried decimate modifier but no use.

Comment: could you please pack your images (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file (copy paste the URL it will give your)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Blend size is causing issues in uploading so I uploaded it to google drive. Please check https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UA6AKIhEteSzc3o3qE6WJOtrRotY3ySu/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a subdivision modifier to your plane like this:

[image]

and you get:

[image]

Comment: I had earlier applied a subdivision modifier. So is my earlier intensity was less to resolve the issue?

Comment: Looks like …when I added the subsurf the problem was gone